# has anyone tried scrambling whites, then stirring in yolks?

Tags: scrambled-eggs

I'm obviously not near my kitchen...

I was reading on lifehacker about cornstarch in scrambled eggs, then some of their other articles on scrambled eggs, and I was thinking that the thing I miss most with scramble eggs is that golden, runny yolk that I shoot for with eggs over easy.  also, I'm just not  a fan of runny whites.

so, anything bad come to mind with:

1. separate eggs, pasteurized eggs, of course
2. heat pan with fat
3. add whites & fat as you would for regular scrambled eggs
4. remove from heat, season
5. allow to cool a bit if necessary
6. stir in yolks

Comment: You might like the texture you get when you crack the eggs into the pan, let them cook for a moment, then start the scrambling.  See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/79668/67

Comment: @Joe looking forward to trying this tomorrow morning!

Comment: Do you want scrambled eggs, or over-easy?

Comment: tried Joe's suggested crack, cook for a bit, and scramble.  great texture, nice to be able to tune both the browning of the whites and runniness of the yolks, but a lot of the yolk stayed on the pan.  thank you!

Comment: tried scrambling the whites, then stirring in the yolks.  if it's too runny for your taste, then zap in the microwave for 15-20 seconds.  much easier pan cleanup. delicious and I'll be making my scrambled eggs this way from now on